# Confusion over conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

### The Question

> A company is considering a marketing campaign for a product which
> currently is purchased by $4\%$ of people. If the company decides to
> run a newspaper campaign then based on previous similar campaigns, the
> Market Research Company states that the probability that an arbitrary
> person (person selected at random) sees the advert is $0.55$.
>
> Also, the Market Research Company assumes that a person who sees the
> advert will be twice as likely to purchase the product (i.e. $8\%$ of
> people). Given that a person had bought the product, what is the
> conditional probability that they had seen the adverts?

### My Understanding

I'm just practicing for a basic maths exam and would just appreciate some clarity on how to calculate conditional probabilities. This is my attempt:

$$\frac{0.55 \cdot 0.08}{ 0.08} + \frac{0.45 \cdot 0.04}{0.04} = 0.2475$$

Am I heading in the right direction or am I completely wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I believe your arithmetic is incorrect. $\frac{0.55 \cdot 0.08}{ 0.08} + \frac{0.45 \cdot 0.04}{0.04} = 1$ (not $0.2475$)

Answer (score 3):

Given the data

- $\mathbb{P}[\text{Purchase}|\overline{\text{Adv}}]=0.04$
- $\mathbb{P}[\text{Purchase}|\text{Adv}]=0.08$

You are requesting to calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Adv}|\text{Purchase}]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[\text{Adv}\cap\text{Purchase}]}{\mathbb{P}[\text{Purchase}]}=\frac{0.55\cdot0.08}{0.55\cdot0.08+0.45\cdot0.04}\approx 70.97\%$$